# Fetcher failure for URL linphone

Tags: yocto

Fetcher failure for URL: 'https://gitlab.linphone.org/BC/public/external/polarssl.git'. Missing SRC_URI checksum. any pointers is appreciated. able to browse the link

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When fetching a project from `git` there is no obligation for checksum.

The checksum specification is needed for files sources (.tar.gz, ...etc).

So, I create a simple recipe for the URL you specified:

```
SUMMARY = "PolarSSL recipe"
LICENSE = "CLOSED"

PROTOCOL = "https"

BRANCH = "linphone-1.4"

GIT_SRC = "gitlab.linphone.org/BC/public/external/polarssl.git"

SRC_URI = "git://${GIT_SRC};protocol=${PROTOCOL};branch=${BRANCH}"

SRCREV = "9864c92b71b81dd1dda885eae108cc3fc9a0cf4b"

S = "${WORKDIR}/git"

inherit autotools
```

I got `SRCREV` value from the last commit on the `linphone-1.4` branch.

I didn't go further with specifying the corrent `LICENSE` and `do_install`.

I tested this recipe with a `zeus` build.