# Unable to fetch repositories using Yocto

Tags: git, github, fetch, repository, yocto

I am trying to build a Yocto image but it keeps failing on trying to fetch the GIT repositories as below. I can reach `https://github.com/PROJECT/linux-imx` from a browser, but no joy fetching the GIT repository from Yocto. Any ideas on how to solve it would be appreciated.

```
 WARNING: linux-imx-5.4-r0 do_fetch: Failed to fetch URL git://github.com/PROJECT/linux-imx.git;protocol=https;branch=master
```

Comment: `git://` protocol is [no longer supported](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70663523/7976758) at GitHub. Use `https://` or `ssh://`

Comment: @phd Thanks for your rely. When I change the protocol to https, it still doesn't work :  linux-imx-5.4-r0 do_fetch: Fetcher failure for URL: 'https: //github.com/ PROJECT/ linux-imx.git;protocol=https;branch=master'. Missing SRC_URI checksum

Answer (score 1):

When you want to have a `git` source then you need to use `git` but you need to specify the protocol as well.

Format: `git://URL;protocol=PROTOCOL;branch=BRANCH`
Also you need to specify the revision with `SRCREV`

For `https` protocol the repo needs to be public, if it is private then you need to save your git credentials to the system's `git` configuration.

For `ssh` protocol then you need to set up your public ssh key in your github account.

So, for your project, it would look like this:

```bash
SRC_URI = "git://github.com/PROJECT/linux-imx;protocol=https;branch=BRANCH"
SRCREV = "aaaa.."
```

or

```bash
SRC_URI = "git://github.com/PROJECT/linux-imx;protocol=ssh;branch=BRANCH"
SRCREV = "aaaa.."
```

It remains to set the `branch` and `SRCREV`

`SRCREV` is the commit hash that you want to fetch.

Regarding the problem you faced lately which is `Missing SRC_URI checksum` is that if you set the `SRC_URI` protocol to `https` instead of `git` like:

```bash
SRC_URI = "https://github.com/PROJECT/linux-imx"
```

then, bitbake will assume that `linux-imx` is a regular file to download, then it will look for `SRC_URI` checksum to verify the integrity of the file which in your case don't needed.

Answer (score 0):

> `Missing SRC_URI checksum`

- either you can try and [turning off Source Checksum Check Yocto](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34803432/6309)
- or [setting the SRCREV checksum associated to SRC_URI](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68673777/6309), using the latest commit of the default branch.